# Google Cloud Deployment Failure-Java 11,cloud sdk 288.0.0 ,builder:java11_20200223_11_0_RC00

Tags: gcloud, java-11, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-sdk, google-app-engine-deploy

I'm trying to deploy a Java 11 Maven project in App Engine(Standard), using **mvn appengine:deploy** command.
It was successful until last week.
This week after Google cloud sdk got updated to 288.0.0 the deployment is failing with below error.
i tried reverting Cloud SDK version but still the issue persists.

Project Id is of format- **google.com:abc-xyz**

Cloud Build Log Snippet below:

```
....

Finished Step #2 - "detector"

Starting Step #3 - "analyzer"

Step #3 - "analyzer": Already have image (with digest): us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/java11/builder:java11_20200223_11_0_RC00

Step #3 - "analyzer": ERROR: failed to access previous image: could not parse reference: us.gcr.io/**google.com:abc-xyz**/app-engine-tmp/ttl-7d/default/buildpack-app:latest

Finished Step #3 - "analyzer"

ERROR

ERROR: build step 3 "us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/java11/builder:java11_20200223_11_0_RC00" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your error appears to be a result of the project ID `google.com:${ID}`

The causes an error for Container Registry because it wants e.g.

`[us.]gcr.io/${PROJECT}/${IMAGE}...`

but it's getting

`[us.]gcr.io/google.com:${PROJECT}..`

IIRC `google.com:` is a defunct method of specifying projects. You should just use `${PROJECT}` without any domain prefixing.

Hmmm... you said that the project is in production and this used to work. I think this is possibly (effectively) a breaking change for you. I'll Google it but, using domain prefixes (`google.com:`) used to be a thing in GCP and perhaps this is now formally deprecated. Guess (!?).

Comment: Thanks Daz, you're right it's because of the project id.I use App engine maven plugin to deploy.I tried providing  abc-xyz,google.com/abc-xyz in projectId tag in pom but get an error initially itself, telling invalid project id if i do so.Im not sure if anything needs to be changed here to change the path.    
Before when the deployment was succesfull there seems to be only 2 steps as seen in cloud build logs 1.fetcher 2.builder.Now there seems to be 8 steps 1.fetcher 2.prep  3.detector 4.analyzer 5.restorer 6.builder 7.exporter 8.deployment-tag
it fails in analyzer step.

Comment: I encountered this issue once before. IIRC we swapped the project ID as you've done and that addressed it. When I get to my desk, I'll find that issue for you. You may want to file an issue with Google Cloud support?

Comment: Sorry I brain-farted and forgot to lookup the previous question|answer. I am unable to find it. You should remove "google.com:" entirely from your project references. The correct project ID would be: `abc-xyz`.

Comment: I found this suggesting that your approach in replacing ":" with "/" should work (https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/overview#domain-scoped_projects). I'm outta ideas, sorry.

Comment: Thanks,I had a look at that link, its for  deployment through Docker file, nothing mentioned for pom file.I tried various combinations of project id, but i get an error telling Invalid project id in build phase itself , if i done give google.com:abc-xyz in pom.

Comment: File a support ticket?

Comment: Yes will raise a  ticket for now.